# Year field missing in EndNote export to bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using TexStudio for my paper

I created refrences list using EndNotes 9

In all the references that I have, I can see they all have year

[image]

But they year is not showing in some of the references in the .bib file

[image]

and therefore it does not show the year in the pdf file.

How to force EndNotes to send Year with other reference info?

**Edit**

Here is the bib content

```
@article{RN24,
   author = {Dafflon, Jessica and Pinaya, Walter HL and Turkheimer, Federico and Cole, James H and Leech, Robert and Harris, Mathew A and Cox, Simon R and Whalley, Heather C and McIntosh, Andrew M and Hellyer, Peter J},
   title = {An automated machine learning approach to predict brain age from cortical anatomical measures},
   journal = {Human Brain Mapping},
   ISSN = {1065-9471},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN30,
   author = {Faes, Livia and Wagner, Siegfried K and Fu, Dun Jack and Liu, Xiaoxuan and Korot, Edward and Ledsam, Joseph R and Back, Trevor and Chopra, Reena and Pontikos, Nikolas and Kern, Christoph},
   title = {Automated deep learning design for medical image classification by health-care professionals with no coding experience: a feasibility study},
   journal = {The Lancet Digital Health},
   volume = {1},
   number = {5},
   pages = {e232-e242},
   ISSN = {2589-7500},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@inproceedings{RN7,
   author = {Feurer, Matthias and Klein, Aaron and Eggensperger, Katharina and Springenberg, Jost and Blum, Manuel and Hutter, Frank},
   title = {Efficient and robust automated machine learning},
   booktitle = {Advances in neural information processing systems},
   pages = {2962-2970},
   type = {Conference Proceedings}
}

@article{RN61,
   author = {Garla, Vijay N and Brandt, Cynthia},
   title = {Ontology-guided feature engineering for clinical text classification},
   journal = {Journal of biomedical informatics},
   volume = {45},
   number = {5},
   pages = {992-998},
   ISSN = {1532-0464},
   year = {2012},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Output style is **BibTeX Export**

Edit

I noticed that when refrenece has a field called "Year" it shows ok.

but for some references the field called "Year of Conference" then it does not show !

Now my question is how to add a new field called "Year"

[image]

Comment: Please show us the actual contents of the bib file -- not a screenshot of the code, but the code itself -- for the entries that are giving you grief.

Comment: @Mico I added that to the question

Comment: Thanks. Please also tell us which document class and which bibliography style you employ. Incidentally, the entry with key `RN7` doesn't appear to have a `year` field.

Comment: @Mico it is "BibTeX Export"

Comment: Let me repeat my questions: (a) Which document class do you employ? (b) Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: @Mico As I understand the question, the document class and bibliography style are not particularly relevant. The problem is that `RN7` does not get a `year` field on export, even though there is a year filled in for it in EndNote (cf. the first screenshot).

Comment: @asmgx Make sure that the `.bib` file you are seeing is the one you think EndNote is exporting to. Make sure that the exported file is up to date. If all that doesn't help, I'm afraid I have no other good suggestion. From what I have seen on forums, EndNote's `.bib` export is not really as good as you would expect from a software that claims to support BibTeX. Can you play around and see if all `@inproceedings` entries lose their `year`. If that's the case a workaround may be to use a different entry type...

Comment: @moewe 
I noticed that when refrenece has a field called "Year" it shows ok.

but for some references the field called "Year of Conference" then it does not show !

Now my question is how to add a new field called "Year"

Comment: This seems like something required from EndNote, not (La)TeX, and therefore off topic. Regardless, see https://canterbury.libguides.com/endnote/FAQ-editing-styles.

Comment: Clearly this has been a problem for a long time, and never fixed. https://community.endnote.com/t5/EndNote-Styles-Filters-and/Missing-year-in-BibTeX-export-of-Conference-Proceedings-entries/td-p/20169

Comment: @Werner Although I agree that EndNote questions are generally off topic, I think this one might be useful to others since it specifically deals with a quirk in the export to bibtex. (I know you haven't voted to close, but I've added this comment in case others do.)

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the solution

Posting it here so other people have the same problem can find the solution

The problem is that conference papers do not have "Year" field.

instead they have "Year of Conference"

To fix this issue.

I went to **Edit > Output Styles > Edit BibTex Export**

[image]

Then Choose "**Template**" from the left side menu and scrolled down to "**Conference Proceedings**"

In the "**Year**" field I chnaged the value to ***{Year.of.Conference}***

[image]

That fixed it